# Scrapy - Handling a page which loads with 404 status code

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy

[This](https://www.classifiedads.com/search.php?keywords=&cid=468&lid=rx10&lname=India&from=s&page=1) is the website I'm scraping. The ads in the pages are loading without any problem, but they are always loading with 404 status code, so scrapy doesn't yield items from those links.

If I send a request from shell to an ad, it retries 10 times and a valid response is returned. However, when I run the script with `scrapy crawl myspider` command, the ads don't return valid responses, scrapy tries to send request single time.

This is the error code from random items.

```
2019-07-30 15:33:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.classifiedads.com/homes_for_sale/57c10snzt1wzz> (failed 1 times): 404 Not Found
2019-07-30 15:33:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.classifiedads.com/homes_for_sale/49zbgqvx21wzz> (failed 1 times): 404 Not Found
2019-07-30 15:33:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.classifiedads.com/homes_for_sale/49482b3hq1wzz> (failed 1 times): 404 Not Found
```

This is my spiders code. How can I handle this problem?

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.classifiedads.com/search.php?keywords=&cid=468&lid=rx10&lname=India&from=s&page=1',
        'https://www.classifiedads.com/search.php?keywords=&cid=18&lid=rx10&lname=India&page=1'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'https://www.classifiedads.com/search.php\?keywords=&cid=468&lid=rx10&lname=India&from=s&page=\d+',)), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'https://www.classifiedads.com/search.php\?keywords=&cid=18&lid=rx10&lname=India&page=\d+',)), callback='parse_page', follow=True)
    )

    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': 1,

    }

    def parse_page(self, response):
        items = response.css('div#results div.resultitem div a::attr(href)').getall()

        if items:
            for item in items:
                if item.startswith('//www.classifiedads.com/'):
                    yield scrapy.Request(
                        url='https:{}'.format(item),
                        method='GET',
                        headers=self.headers,
                        callback=self.parse_items
                    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        # scraping the items
```

Comment: The 404 code means "Page not found", so there is nothing *to* load.

Answer (score 2):

[Pass `'handle_httpstatus_list': [404]` in the `meta` parameter of your requests](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-handle_httpstatus_list) to handle 404 responses with your callback, if they are sending valid responses with 404 as status code.

Comment: I'm already doing that. That's why scrapy keeps trying to send request to the same url.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check these [retry settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=max%20retry#retrymiddleware-settings) first of all and add 404 status code to `RETRY_HTTP_CODES`. Another solution is to create `errback` function and add it to your Request. But all these solutions aren't good. Did you try to add some headers, cookies?

Comment: I don't think it is about headers because when I do it from Chrome with all default request headers, the page returns 404 again. The weird thing is page loads without any problem at all in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The server is throwing 404 response.
You can also check it in your terminal
`>>> 
import requests
requests.get('https://www.classifiedads.com/commercial_for_rent/9144lxkm81wxd')
<Response [404]>`

You can try it with selenium.

Comment: It throws 404 on chrome as well, but the page loads.